# Assign & Output vector of vector<int>

Tags: c++, vector

The code below generates the resulting output, that is perfectly fine which I need. But I want to save each of those modified `vector<int>` in an another vector and then get the output by printing `vector<vector<int>>` elements.

I got a template that delivers a formatted output of a vector, but it fails to print an element of `vector<vector<int>>`, check by un-commenting code snippets.

Why is this behavior?

How to first assign and then print `vector<vector<int>>` elements, such that output remains same as now?

*Using C++14(4.9.2)*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define s(n)                        scanf("%d",&n)

template<typename T>
inline std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream & os,const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    bool first = true;
    os << "[";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!first)
            os << ", ";
        os << v[i];
        first = false;
    }
    return os << "]";
}

typedef vector<int> vi; 
typedef vector< vi > vvi; 

int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    // s(n);

    vi list(n, 1);

    // vvi rlist;
    // int count = 0;
    // rlist[count++] = list;
    cout << list << "\n";

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = n; j >= i; --j)
        {
            while(list[j] == list[j-1])
            {
                ++list[j];
                cout << list << "\n";
                // rlist[count++] = list;
            }
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) by KerrekSB.

Comment: you need to initialize `rlist` with a count in order to use square brackets. http://ideone.com/XY7pdJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've commented out `// rlist[count++] = list;`

That's presumably because it fails. `rlist` is empty, it doesn't have element `[0]` yet so you can't assign to it. But you don't want to assign to `[0]`, you want to create it. The easiest way to do this is `rlist.push_back(list);`.